# Getting rid of unwanted padding on a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I've created a custom UITableViewCell in Interface Builder. (see the design view below)
[Design view http://www.zininsushi.nl/IBview.png](http://www.zininsushi.nl/IBview.png)

Notice that the image and labels are all reasonable positioned and there is almost no top & left padding.

But when displayed in a UITableView it looks like the image below. What do I need to do to get rid of the unwanted padding? I believe that also caused the bad (re) positioning of the image & labels.

[alt text http://www.zininsushi.nl/Favorites.png](http://www.zininsushi.nl/Favorites.png)

Answer (score 2):

Found a way to solve this issue. First add a UIView that spans the whole contentview, and then add the labels and such like before. All will be well now.